# delete query not working with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete records by `joins` of `tables` but it is not working.

My query is :

```
DELETE FROM category
WHERE  catid NOT IN(SELECT av.catid
                    FROM   category av
                           JOIN rel
                             ON rel.catid = av.catid
                           JOIN main_list
                             ON rel.webid = main_list.mainid
                    GROUP  BY av.catid)
```

Why is this query not working? It's throwing the following error:

`#1093 - You can't specify target table 'category' for update in FROM clause`

How do I fix this? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong by the error.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  You're trying to delete rows from `category` where they don't exist in `category`.

Comment: He's trying to delete rows from category that don't exist in rel, and main_list.  That does make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
DELETE  av
FROM    category av
        LEFT JOIN rel ON rel.catid = av.catid
        LEFT JOIN main_list ON rel.webid = main_list.mainid 
WHERE   rel.catid IS NULL
```

<sup>*Please backup your database before executing this query.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

try this::

```
DELETE c from  category c
LEFT join rel  ON rel.catid = av.catid
LEFT JOIN main_list  ON rel.webid = main_list.mainid
where rel.catid is null
```

or

```
DELETE FROM category
WHERE  catid NOT IN(
Select catid from 
(SELECT av.catid as catid
                    FROM   category av
                           JOIN rel
                             ON rel.catid = av.catid
                           JOIN main_list
                             ON rel.webid = main_list.mainid
                    GROUP  BY av.catid)  as tempCat)
```